# String parsing inside a makefile

Tags: makefile

I need to parse a string inside a Makefile and fetch the value assigned to the variable parsed in the string.
String contains this data "Days=false;export Day;EXTRACT=true;export EXTRACT".
First i need to check if a variable(for eg Days)  is present in the string.if it exists want to get the value of the variable.

i tried findstring function i can verify variable is present in string but i find  how to get the value assigned to the variable.`str1 := Days='true';export Days;EXTRACT=true;export EXTRACT;
a := $(findstring Days=, $(str1))`

Comment: If the string is known/guaranteed to be a set of shell assignments I would just run them through the shell and `echo` the value you want at the end of the `$(shell)` call to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 := Days='true';export Days;EXTRACT=true;export EXTRACT;

define VARIABLE_EQ_VALUE_IN_STRING
$(eval $(filter $1=%, $(subst ;, ,$2)))
endef

$(call VARIABLE_EQ_VALUE_IN_STRING,Days, $(str1))
```

After this code, `$(Days)` is `'true'`

On the other hand, if `str1` did not contain an assignment to `Days` then after this code, `Days` would be undefined.

Comment: Thanks it works fine for single values.but i have sometimes values as numeric list eg Days='1 3 5' where it fails.can you suggest changes to get those values correctly.I am unable to upvote your answer as i don't have required reputation.

Comment: In that case I would probably second Etan's answer.